# Исправить кодировку в shp-файле

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, r, rstudio

При открытии в RStudio [вот этого](http://gisgeo.org/assets/files/Moscow_region.zip) shp-файла слетает кодировка и все значения предстают в виде "крякозябр". Большого опыта работы с shp-файлами не имею, и не знаю, как именно сделать так, чтобы они открывались в читаемом виде.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
> MosRegions <- readShapePoly("/Moscow_region.shp")


>MosRegions@data
```

А дальше, собственно, идет сбитая кодировка:

> NAME                                     OKATO_NAME
> 0                       РћСЂРµС…РѕРІРѕ-Р—СѓРµРІСЃРєРёР№ СЂР°Р№РѕРЅ     РћСЂРµС…РѕРІРѕ-Р—СѓРµРІСЃРєРёР№ СЂР°Р№РѕРЅ
> 1                                             РњРѕР»РѕРґС‘Р¶РЅС‹Р№                           РњРѕР»РѕРґРµР¶РЅС‹Р№
> 2                     РџР°РІР»РѕРІРѕ-РџРѕСЃР°РґСЃРєРёР№ СЂР°Р№РѕРЅ   РџР°РІР»РѕРІРѕ-РџРѕСЃР°РґСЃРєРёР№ СЂР°Р№РѕРЅ
> 3                                РљРѕР»РѕРјРµРЅСЃРєРёР№ СЂР°Р№РѕРЅ              РљРѕР»РѕРјРµРЅСЃРєРёР№ СЂР°Р№РѕРЅ

Comment: без rstudio всё нормально? значит в самой этой программе у вас не согласованы кодировки, используемые для работы как таковой программы r и отображения интерфейса программы rstudio. поройтесь по меню на предмет кодировки (конкретного ничего не подскажу, потому что ни разу в жизни не пользовался таким профессиональным инструментом, как программа rstudio: я не профессионал и одной лишь программы r для моих задач более чем достаточно).

Comment: в виде сопутствующей информации: `РћСЂРµС…РѕРІРѕ-Р—СѓРµРІСЃРєРёР№` — это представленная в utf8 и насильно перекодированная из cp1251 в utf8 строка `Орехово-Зуевский`. (проверка: `$ echo 'РћСЂРµС…РѕРІРѕ-Р—СѓРµРІСЃРєРёР№' | iconv -f utf8 -t cp1251`)